# How to control error handling and synchronization in Antlr 4 / c#

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm using Antlr 4 with c# target.
Here is a subset of my grammar:

```
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
text : term+  EOF;
term : a1 a2 a3;
a1: ....
...
...
```

I want to accept valid data blocks as (term)s, when error exists I want to search for the next valid term and print out the whole text which caused the error for user to analyze manually.

How to synchronize input to the next valid term? 
and How to get the ignored text?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to create your own implementation of `IAntlrErrorStrategy` for this, and then set the `Parser.ErrorHandler` property to an instance of your error strategy. The documentation for the Java versions of the [`ANTLRErrorStrategy`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorStrategy.html) interface and default implementation [`DefaultErrorStrategy`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.html) may provide useful information for implementing an error strategy, but I must warn you going in that creating a custom error strategy is an advanced feature with limited documentation. It's expected that the implementer is already an expert in ANTLR 4's implementation of the Adaptive LL(*) parsing algorithm (we're talking researcher-level understanding).

Comment: Thanks Mr. Harwell, (It's the second time you answer me for two similar questions. so, thank you very much , but ,in both, you gave me a very general answer, I still can not find a solution.)

If I just wanted to get the ignored text when error occurred. How could i find it?

Comment: There is no simple solution here that is not "very general". Each time I've needed something special regarding error handling, I rolled my own custom solution that was specific to the particular language I was parsing *and* the application I was developing.

Comment: In `DefaultErrorStrategy` documentation, there is something about [recover](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.html#recover(org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser,%20org.antlr.v4.runtime.RecognitionException)) method says that recover method will consume tokens until resynchronization, can we collect consumed tokens? (I'm trying to extend `DefaultErrorStrategy`).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Harwell,I found some useful information, I put it in an answer and hope you advice me if there is better solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question (How to synchronize input to the next valid term?) I found some useful information that led me to acceptable solution.

Antlr generates next subcode for previous grammar:

```java
public TextContext text() {
    TextContext _localctx = new TextContext(_ctx, State);
    EnterRule(_localctx, 0, RULE_text);
    int _la;
    try {
        EnterOuterAlt(_localctx, 1);
        State = 49;
        _errHandler.Sync(this);
        _la = _input.La(1);
        do {
            State = 48; term();
            State = 51;
            _errHandler.Sync(this);
            _la = _input.La(1);
        } while ( _la==KEYWORD );
        State = 53; Match(EOF);
    }
    catch (RecognitionException re) {
        _localctx.exception = re;
        _errHandler.ReportError(this, re);
        _errHandler.Recover(this, re);
    }
    finally {
        ExitRule();
    }
    return _localctx;
}
```

The call `_errHandler.Sync(this);` makes the parser advances through the input stream in an attempt to find next valid turn (as a result of  "term+" component).
To stop parser from sync in other subrules accept "term" rule", I Extended `DefaultErrorStrategy` Class as next:

```java
public class MyErrorStrategy : Antlr4.Runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy
{
    public EventErrorStrategy() : base()
    { }

    public override void Sync(Antlr4.Runtime.Parser recognizer)
    {
        if(recognizer.Context is Dict.TextAnalyzer.DictionaryParser.TextContext)
            base.Sync(recognizer);
    }
}
```

then provided it to the parser:

```java
parser.ErrorHandler = new MyErrorStrategy();
```