# move to a new state after cosuming tokens in antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlrworks

i have following grammar

```
root
    : sql_statements EOF | EOF
   ;

sql_statements
    :( sql_statement )+
   ;

sql_statement
    : ddl_statement semicolon
   ;

ddl_statement
    : alter_statement
   ;
```

This is a initial snapshot of my grammar
i have following test case

```
aleter table user;alter table group_user;
```

first statement has error hence i am getting error for both statements under sql_statements rule

```
Failed to parse at line 1:1 due to mismatched input 'aleter' expecting ALTER
```

Now i want to use Defaulterrorhandler functionality to skip first statement till semicolon. 
Then it should start from second statement starting with rule sql_statements.

```
Question :
How to tell which rule to start after consuming error tokens ?
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Could you please update with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  For example, not enough of your grammar file is supplied to reproduce your referenced error, which I know is not the target of your question, but it is the starting point for further research.