# Generate specific warning/error messages from Antlr4 Listener

Tags: antlr4

I am using Antlr4 to tokenize and parse a legacy language, my end goal is to generate C# code and execute this code in a runtime environment that simulates the physical hardware that executes the legacy language.

The simulator and code generation is working very well.

I would like to generate specific error messages or warning messages from the listener, is this possible?

For example the language allows a line to end or not end in a semi-colon, I would like to issue a warning if a line is missing a semi-colon.

I have many more similar scenarios, the language and physical hardware have a number of bizarre characteristics.

Thanks,
Gregg

Answer (score 1):

The likely better approach would be to issue the warnings from the parser.  In the construction of the parser, there are two methods:

```
parser.addErrorListener(new YourErrorListener());
parser.setErrorHandler(new YourParserErrorStrategy());
```

The error listener allows [custom error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700576/antlr4-unexpected-behavior-that-i-cant-understand/30701061#30701061).  The error strategy controls how the parser [deals with specific errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550031/how-to-control-error-handling-and-synchronization-in-antlr-4-c-sharp): re-sychronizing with the token stream or effectively inserting 'missing' tokens.

Comment: Your suggesting that I demand a ";" at the end of the line. If the line is missing the semi-colon I would add the semi-colon and issue a custom error message.  I will give this a try.

Comment: If having the semicolon (or other 'bizarre' circumstance token) present makes subsequent analysis of the parse tree easier/more regular, make it non-optional (guess that is what you meant by demand) and add it when missing.  Can go the other way as well: skipping over extra/unexpected tokens dependent on whether the ErrorStrategy determines they are significant or not -- it can warn, fixup, or bail.